# Modal element vertical align is not responding to any CSS, no Idea what it could be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Modal View]

I have tried every single possible CSS selector I can find to move the login button underneath the two input boxes, with nothing working. 
Putting different attributes in the html tags did nothing, as did putting the form inside a div and a secondary div, with neither of these working either. 
I will post the code below, it seems like such a simple thing to do but I can't spot where the conflicting CSS attributes are.

CSS code:

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
padding-top: 60px;
height: 100vh;
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#modal-login-button {
    margin: auto;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: center;



}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 66%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
height: 66vh;
border-radius: 20px;
z-index: 1000;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
align-content: left;
margin: auto;


}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
position: relative;
margin: 2% auto 95% auto;
color: #000;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
 .close:focus {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="id01" class="modal">
                <div id="id02" style="justify-content:center;">
              <form action="loginR.php" class="modal-content animate" method="POST">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                  <input type="text" class="input-txt"  placeholder="Enter Username" name="uid" required>

                  <input type="password" class="input-txt"  placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>

                  <button type="submit" id="modal-login-button">Login</button>
                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This simple piece has wasted hours of my day now, if anyone could save my efforts before I fling the computer down the toilet i'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: please create a fiddle and share....

Comment: Hey Andrew, quite a bit of the CSS you've got in there isn't going to be doing anything. For example `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` is redundant and `justify-content` only works with flexbox items.

While it's okay to experiment, I'd suggest cleaning up your code when something doesn't work so you don't create bloated, confusing css.

Regarding your actual issue. i'd suggest centering `.container` and letting the inner contents naturally position themselves rather than trying to micro-manage all the elements into specific positions

Comment: @Calvin Thanks for the tips, I will look at cleaning the code up a bit. unfortunately the .container didn't respond either, is there something that would be causing the CSS to be ignored?

Comment: @Andrew chrome developer tools are your friend here. Right click the element on the page and click inspect element. From there under the `styles` tab you'll be able to see all CSS rules that are affecting the element (and the file they are from on the right). If there's a line through the rule then it is being overridden by another rule. This could be because of an important tag, because the rule is lower down in the stylesheet or because of specificity (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

If you can't see the CSS rule at all you might not be linking to the file

Comment: ... you can check if a file is being included on the page by either looking for a `<link>` tag in the page source or by looking in the file tree in the `sources` tab in developer tools

Answer (score 0):

```
#modal-login-button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: center;



}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't change the rendering of the modal. I don't know what else to try.